# .NET GraphServiceClient Token Cache

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, token

I am using `Microsoft.Graph` in latest version `5.19.0` and I want to fetch mails from different worker VMs.

At the moment I a authenticate my application and save the resulting `AuthenticationRecord` after successful authentication. This record is deserialized into the `InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions` `AuthenticationRecord` after restarting my application.
This all works fine on my current computer:

```
_interactiveCredentialOptions = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
    TokenCachePersistenceOptions = new()
};

if (IsAuthenticated(mailbox))
{
    _interactiveCredentialOptions.AuthenticationRecord = await ReadTokenCache(mailbox);
}
```

However when I understand the [documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/samples/TokenCache.md) correctly, this only holds true for the current computer. Using the cached `AuthenticationRecord` from another computer will not work.

Is there a token cache mechanism for `GraphServiceClient`, so I can serialize and deserialize tokens on my computer as well as other client PCs as well after authenticating once?

Comment: Have you tried setting `UnsafeAllowUnencryptedStorage = true` in the `TokenCachePersistenceOptions` ?